# Multiple attachements with ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, prawn

I am successfully sending emails with one PDF attachment using action mailer but I now have a need to send multiple PDF attachements in one email. I had hoped I could just pass in my products and loop, rendering a file on each iteration but that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help guide me in the right direction here please? Here's what I have tried:

```
def sales_notes(products)

  products.each do |product|
    pdf = Salesnote.new(product, @user_role)
    @pdf_filename = "#{product.cat_no} - #{product.release.artists.map { |a| a.name}.join (", ")} - #{product.release.title}.pdf"
    mail.attachments[@pdf_filename] = pdf.render
  end  

  mail(:to => "me@mydomain.com", :subject => "SALES NOTES ATTACHED")


  end
```

I have also tried with just `attachments[@pdf_filename]` instead of `mail.attachments[@pdf_filename]`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue in **mail.attachments**. Check whether @pdf_filename value is duplicated or it has more than one values

Comment: @pdf_filename should always be distinct as cat_no is a unique string in my db.

Comment: Then you need to check whether pdf.render returns nil or blank while iterating

Comment: I'm just getting one attachment called 'noname' without an extension. If I open this in a text editor I can see it's headers and it's meant to be a pdf, but appears to be for just one product and not the three i'm expecting in this test case.

Comment: Then @pdf_filename is the code you need to check. Try it by hard coding some values so that you can get the clear picture on the area where you are getting the error

Comment: The 'noname' does actual contain the three sets of headers and they seem to contain the correct filenames so @pdf_filename seem to be ok to me. I still don't understand why i'm getting all three rendered in the 'noname' file. Here's an example of the headers in 'noname' `Date: Thu, 06 Dec 2012 12:21:52 +0000
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/pdf;
 charset=UTF-8;
 filename=CD123456.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=CD123456.pdf`

Comment: I guess the whitespace truncates the remaining part of file name
Also don;t use ',' for filename. Try the following

@pdf_filename = "#{product.cat_no}_#{product.release.artists.map { |a| a.name}.join ("_")}_#{product.release.title}.pdf"

Comment: Wow! I have solved it. I neglected to write a view for this mailer! With the view in place the PDFs render as they should. Thanks for your help even though this was a silly mistake. Your tip regarding file names truncating has been useful too.